# Rest service adding an extra parameter throws error

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I am trying to create a REST service with body. When I try to add an extra parameter(to read POST body), the rest request does not get invoked.

1st JAVA CLASS:

```
@Path("{module}/{messageKey}")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response status(final @Context HttpServletRequest request, @PathParam("module") final String module, @PathParam("messageKey") final String messageKey, final GetMessageDAO dao) {
        String messageText = "";
System.out.println(messageKey);
        CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl();
        cacheControl.setNoCache(true);
        return Response.ok(String.valueOf(messageText)).cacheControl(cacheControl).build();
    }
```

2nd Java Class:

```
public class GetMessageDAO {

    @JsonProperty("args")
    private String args;

    public String getArgs() {
        return args;
    }

    public void setArgs(String args) {
        this.args = args;
    }
}
```

JS Call:

```
    new Ajax.Request(
          '/ecmws/resources/message/gp/transactionManager.confirm.affected_calc_req', 
          {
            method: 'post',
            parameter: {args: "abc"},
data: {args: "abc"},
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            charset: 'UTF-8',
            async: false});
```

The moment I remove the last parameter from 1st Java class, it works fine but I need to read POST body as well and hence the problem.

I have jersey-core, jersey-json, jersey-client, jersey-server, jackson-mapper all in classpath.

Can you please suggest what I am missing?

Comment: How your class is registered ? do you have @ApplicationPath ResourceConfig class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is **NOT** with your **Jersey Controller**, but it is with the way you are sending data in your **AJAX** call.

If you make a **postman** call or **curl** your request, you will probably not have any issues and method even with GetMessageDAO will be invoked as expected. But making an ajax call from browser will fail.

```
curl --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/todos/hello/world' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{"args":"b"}'
```

To fix this issue change your line

```
data: {args: "abc"},
```

to

```
data: JSON.stringify({args: 'abc'}),
```

FURTHER (to verify):

If you check your browser network request, data **without** JSON.stringify is sent as

```
args=abc
```

but chaning it to JSON.stringify changes it to JSON String and you will be see data being sent is:

```
{"args": "abc"}
```

Which then can be marshalled to `GetMessageDAO` class instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you will follow [jersey example project](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/master/examples/json-jackson/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/examples/jackson/MyApplication.java) you must have application class extending `ResourceConfig` which should include your class and `JacksonFeature` class

> ```
> public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
>      public MyApplication() {
>         super(
>            EmptyArrayResource.class,
>            NonJaxbBeanResource.class,
>            CombinedAnnotationResource.class,
>            // register Jackson ObjectMapper resolver
>            MyObjectMapperProvider.class,
>            ExceptionMappingTestResource.class,
>            JacksonFeature.class
>    );
> ```

Answer (score 0):

- In your Appplication, instantiate your `GetMessageDAO` class (for that matter any DAO class) upfront and pass it as a constructor parameter of "1st Java class".
- In constructor of "1st Java class", set `GetMessageDAO` as field variable
- In method `status`, access the field variable.

Answer (score 0):

Add [jersey-media-json-jackson denepndency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-json-jackson) to your project.

It is support module for JSON Jackson.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to use the `@FormParam` or the `@BeanForm` annotation:

```
@POST
public String delivery(@FormParam("deliveryAddress") String deliveryAddress,
                       @FormParam("quantity") Long quantity) 
{
    return "Form parameters are " +
            "[deliveryAddress=" + deliveryAddress + ", quantity=" + quantity + "]";
}
```

You need to set the correct Content-Type to mimic the form submission action. \

To set the form parameters you use the -d flag:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
   -d 'deliveryAddress=Street 1A&quantity=5' \
   http://localhost:8080/application/delivery
```

Output:

```
Form parameters are [deliveryAddress=Street 1A, quantity=5]
```